# How to write to a web page with an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors script print out onto the webpage it's loaded on but it doesn't seem to show up. The prompt comes up but the result that I want it to print out isn't working.

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minigames for All</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h2 id="header">Welcome to Minigames for All.</h2>
    <hr>
    <script src="rps.js"></script>
    <hr>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="rps.html">Rock, Paper, Scissors</td>
                <td><a href="random.html">Guess the Number</td>
                <td><a href="ttt.html">Tic Tac Toe</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td><a href="flip.html">Flip a Coin</td>
                <td><a href="rpg.html">Slime RPG</td>
                <td><a href="shoot.html">Space Shooter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

JS file:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

userChoice=userChoice.toLower();

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) 
{

    computerChoice = "rock";

} 
else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) 
{

    computerChoice = "paper";

} 
else 
{

computerChoice = "scissors";

}


var compare = function (choice1, choice2)

{

    if(choice1 === choice2)

        {

        document.write ("The result is a tie!");

        }


    if(choice1 === "rock")

        {

            if(choice2 === "scissors")

                {

                    document.write ("Computer chose scissors. Rock wins");

                }

            else

                {

                    document.write ("Computer chose paper. Paper wins");

                }

        }


    if(choice1 === "paper")

        {

            if(choice2 === "scissors")

                {

                    document.write ("Computer chose scissors. Scissors wins");

                }

            else

            {

                document.write ("Computer chose rock. Paper wins");

            }

        }


    if(choice1 === "scissors")

        {

            if(choice2 === "paper")

            {

                document.write ("Computer chose paper. Scissors wins");

            }

            else

            {

                document.write ("Computer chose scissors. Rock wins");

            }

        }

};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Any idea how to make this show up? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe adding an interactive element for the user to interact with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
userChoice=userChoice.toLower();
```

With

```
userChoice=userChoice.toLowerCase();
```

and try it again

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed such a simple mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: userChoice.toLower is not a function @ rps.js:3

It should be userChoice=userChoice.toLowerCase();

Answer (score 0):

```
userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
```

instead of:

```
userChoice = userChoice.toLower();
```